# I can't track website visitors

Tags: ee2

I'm new in EE, I was wondering is there anyway I can track the visitors that enter to my EE website?

Where do I click-on to see the # website visitors?

Please help me :)

Answer (score 2):

[Google Analytics](http://google.com/analytics)?

You can track individual views to entries by using the [track_views](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#track-views) parameter in your Channel Entries tag, so this could be mapped to individual pages.

Or possibly your hosting has tracking built in...?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [track-views functionality](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/hit_counter.html) for individual channel entries, there's also the [referrers module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/referrer/) and template, but what it shows you is kind of limited (who landed on which page coming from where, using what IP and user-agent, basically.) More on that referrer module, and its template, in the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/referrer/).

(I would use the referrer template as a quick-check, but DEFINITELY back it up with something far more thorough like Google Analytics.)

Edit: there's also a way to display the number of total hits and unique visitors. That's the [stats module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/statistics/).